# Check instanceof of autowired Proxy in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

With Spring and Spring Boot Web it is barely an inconvenience to inject the current request. Just add it to the bean as follows:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    // ..
}
```

That works. The injected request is a `Proxy` that enables access to all request methods.

However there could be multiple types of a `HttpServletRequest` as in most cases it will be wrapped, e.g. the `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`.

Is there a way to check for the `instanceof` the injected request? It does not work as the injected request is of type `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy`.

That fails:

```
if (request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
    // ..
}
```

Is there a way to do it? Or at least get the real class name of the bean behind the `Proxy`?

---

In case of the request there is a workaround:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
if (request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
    // ..
}
```

That works. But that is unsatisfying and will not work for `Proxy` aside requests.

Comment: Note that there can be multiple wrappers as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe a `javax.inject.Provider` might do the job:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private Provider<HttpServletRequest> request;

    // ..
}
```

I would assume Spring will not create a proxy in this case, allowing you to access the current request directly. You will have to check, though

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately it does not work. The Provider gives me the same Proxy. I tried it with Spring Boot 2.4 and 1.5. I even tried it with Optional<HttpServletRequest>.